# How to set a textbox readonly property true or false 

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I need your help in creating a textbox readonly property  true or false based on a condition.
I tried however was unsuccessful.
Below is my sample code:

```
string property= "";
if(x=true)
{
     property="true"
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @readonly = property})
```

My question is: Even though the condition is false I am unable to write or edit the textbox?

Answer (score 9):

This is because the `readonly` attribute in HTML is designed so that it's mere presence indicates a readonly textbox.

I believe that the values `true|false` are completely ignored by the attribute and infact the recomended value is `readonly="readonly"`.

To re-enable the textbox you'll need to get rid of the `readonly` attribute altogether.

Given that the `htmlAttributes` property of `TextBoxFor` is an `IDictionary`, you could simply build the object based on your requirements.

```
IDictionary customHTMLAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();

if(x == true) 
   // Notice here that i'm using == not =. 
   // This is because I'm testing the value of x, not setting the value of x.
   // You could also simplfy this with if(x).
{
customHTMLAttributes.Add("readonly","readonly");
}

@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, customHTMLAttributes)
```

A shorthand way to add the custom attrbute could be:

```
var customHTMLAttributes = (x)? new Dictionary<string,object>{{"readonly","readonly"}} 
                                                          : null;
```

or simply:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, (x)? new {"readonly","readonly"} : null);
```

Comment: The last line does not work. It seems your shorthand test is written wrongly, and its not even possible. I get "Invalid anonymous type member declarator" from Visual Studio editor.

Answer (score 4):

I achieved it using some extension methods

```
public static MvcHtmlString IsDisabled(this MvcHtmlString htmlString, bool disabled)
    {
        string rawstring = htmlString.ToString();
        if (disabled)
        {
            rawstring = rawstring.Insert(rawstring.Length - 2, "disabled=\"disabled\"");
        }
        return new MvcHtmlString(rawstring);
    }

public static MvcHtmlString IsReadonly(this MvcHtmlString htmlString, bool @readonly)
    {
        string rawstring = htmlString.ToString();
        if (@readonly)
        {
            rawstring = rawstring.Insert(rawstring.Length - 2, "readonly=\"readonly\"");
        }
        return new MvcHtmlString(rawstring);
    }
```

and then....

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class= "someclass"}).IsReadonly(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to refactor your code to be something along the lines of

```
if(x)
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @readonly = "readonly"})
}
else
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
}
```

Comment: Note that x=true is always true so you'll always end up with a readonly textbox.

Comment: Sorry, was from my copy/paste of his original.